# create section in global action layout in lightning page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

On Lead Detail Page I have created global action called 'create contact' that will  openup a page called contact and  configured all fields in action layout which are present in contact layout.so,this quick action on lead detail is same as creating new contact on contact object.
But I want the sections to differentiate the fields like system information etc

It is possible in action layout?
Please suggest some info

Answer (score 2):

[image: Quick Action Fields]
As you can see, There is no way to sort or group fields in a section or systematic manner. You can use blank spaces to group together, but that would not contain any headers.

Another approach will be to call a lightning component in quick action. That lightning component will save data using Lightning DATA Services. As its code you can customize it to your need.

Here is a brilliant example of creating contact: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_example.htm

Comment: Thanks for guidance!  I have tried blank spaces but as you mentioned it will not contain headers it makes users to difficult to understand if we don't have sections. like personal information,system information etc

Comment: Instead of quick action is there any way to create a button and that opens a pop up contact page  on lead detail page which support standard functionality and able to see headers as well